# How did Rumpelstiltskin become king without marrying a princess?

Tags: shrek, shrek-forever-after

In *Shrek*, Lord Farquaad can't become king unless he marries a princess. However, in *Shrek Forever After*, Rumpel became King of Far Far Away without needing to marry a princess.

Is this a plot hole or is it because King Harold signed the kingdom to him, thus making him king in his own right?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, King Harold signed the Kingdom off to him, making him king..?

Comment: The same way you usually do, by killing anyone who says "*You aren't the King*"

Comment: The idea that marrying a princess is necessary to become a king is not found in the real world.  In the real world someone usually becomes king by being the oldest son of the previous king.  Other methods include assassinating everyone who has a superior claim, invading and conquering, convincing everyone you'd make a better king than the alternatives, leading a revolution, and yes marrying a princess - the right princess who is the heiress to the throne of the kingdom, and not any old princess of any old kingdom.  So why assume there is only one way to become king in the Shrekverse?

Comment: IIRC, the Magic Mirror suggested that Farquaad marry a princess in order to become a King, but never said that it was the only possible way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The King signed over his kindgom (and the rightful kingship) when he signed the "[Problems Disappear](http://shrek.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_Contract)" magical contract. This is addressed directly in Shrek 4.

> **Harold:** *So you'll put an end to our daughter's curse?*
>
> **Rumpelstiltskin:** *And, in return, **you sign the kingdom of Far Far Away over to me.***

We know, from [Shrek the Third](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Shrek-the-Third.html), that **Harold can designate someone else as King**, based on the fact that Fiona and Shrek (who were the rightful heirs to the throne) choose Artie to be the next King of Far, Far Away.

> **SHREK:** *Oh, come on Dad...an Ogre as King? I don't think that's such a good idea. There's got to be somebody else. Anybody?*
>
> **KING HAROLD:** *Aside from you there is only one remaining heir.*